# Persisting Batch Task Output to Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-batch

I was using [Batch service API to persist task data to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files) but I updated the code to use Azure AD Authentication instead of using Storage and Batch account credentials. And the Batch service API does not work anymore as it requires *Account Key credentials* to generate the [shared access signature for the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files#get-a-shared-access-signature-for-the-container) where I wish to store the output.

The only other way of persisting batch task output I found was to use the [Batch File Conventions library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-file-conventions) but that requires me to make modifications to the task code, which is not an option.

Is there any way I can save the task output to Azure Storage without using a SAS Uri?

Additional information:

1. The Storage Account is linked to the Batch Account.
2. The Service Principal has Storage Blob Data Owner (this is temporary, I plan on using Storage Blob Data Contributor)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if you want to use the built in file upload functionality, only SAS-based  (or in the case of the Batch File Conventions library for .NET - key-based) authentication is supported.

You can request a feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/269742-batch) - there are already some requests there (such as support for managed service identity) which are related to this topic.